# I can't fetch the avatar of author through discord js

Tags: discord.js

I want to fetch the avatar picture of the person who sends the message through a Discord bot. Like the author of the message.

This is my code:

```
     case 'embed':

     const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed() 

    .setAuthor(`From ${message.author.username}`, message.author.avatarURL)


    .setDescription("My Description");
          message.channel.send(embed);
     break;
```

It returns the author's username correctly through `message.author.username` but when I am using `message.author.avatarURL` it's not returning anything. I had tried to use `message.author.defaultAvatarURL` and it works perfectly. But I don't know why avatarURL doesn't show up anything.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In discord.js v12 [`User#avatarURL`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=avatarURL) is a method, not a property, and so you need to call it to get the URL. You can also use [`User#displayAvatarURL`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=displayAvatarURL) to get the either the actual displayed avatar (it links to the default avatar if necessary). Here's an example:

```js
.setAuthor(`From ${message.author.username}`, message.author.avatarURL())
.setAuthor(`From ${message.author.username}`, message.author.displayAvatarURL())
```

Comment: thanks, Already got that fixed, was just missing this point. I was also curious because the message.author.username was colored as blue in vs code and avatarURL was yellow. Thanks BTW, :)

Comment: make sure to accept the answer if it solved your answer.